# How to hide PHPSESSID from PHP sessions

Tags: php, session

How to go about changing the name of a php session from PHPSESSID to something else?

Comment: Why are you concerned about how pretty your cookies are?!

Comment: @David although it's not the motivation here, one argument for changing it *could* be if you don't want to expose your running PHP to the outside world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`session_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php), or change the [PHP configuration setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) to change it globally and permanently.

Important [side notes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php#89090):

> The session name is reset to the default value stored in session.name at request startup time. Thus, you need to call session_name() for every request (and before session_start() or session_register() are called).

and

> Remember, kids--you MUST use `session_name()` first if you want to use `session_set_cookie_params()` to, say, change the session timeout. Otherwise it won't work, won't give any error, and nothing in the documentation (that I've seen, anyway) will explain why.

Comment: @barjonah see the link, the manual has an example. It's trivial really: Just call `session_name("NewValue");` at the beginning of every script

Comment: as session_name is a configuration parameter it can as well be set in php.ini or in apache configuration files with "php_value  session.name "MYSESSIONPHPSESSIDNAME", and then no problem of timeline for this call.